# trying to figure out why my admob ads aren't showing up?

Tags: eclipse, admob

I'm trying to find out what I have done wrong and why my code isn't coming up.

I feel I need to post a screenshot of my project to show where my admob.jar file is located.  I wanted to show this in case anyone feels the location of the .jar is the reason the ads are not showing up.

[image: Here you can see the addmob .jar is not in a referenced libraries or a libs folder]

Here is the code from my manifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.soundboard"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
        ></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Soundboard"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

</manifest>
```

Here is the code from my xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="300dp"

android:orientation="vertical">
<TableLayout
android:id="@+id/tablelayout1"
android:layout_width="312px"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<Button
android:id="@+id/sound1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 1"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 2"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound3"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 3"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound4"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 4"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound5"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 5"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound6"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound Button 6"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound7"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sount Button 7"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound8"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 8"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound9"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound Button 8"
>
</Button>

<Button
android:id="@+id/sound10"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 10"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound11"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 11"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound12"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 12"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound13"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 13"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound14"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 14"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound15"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 15"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound16"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 16"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound17"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 17"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound18"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 18"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound19"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 19"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound20"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 20"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound21"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 21"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound22"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 22"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound23"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 23"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound24"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 24"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound25"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 25"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound26"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound Button 26"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound27"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 27"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound28"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 28"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound29"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 29"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound30"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 30"
>
</Button>
</TableLayout>
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adview"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
ads:adUnitId=""
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I believe the error is somewhere within.

p.s. add id is left blank intentionally for post

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look here](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html#addadview) It's not about implementing the view in your xml. They saying that you should add the AdView in code. 
But if you still wish to play with xml your implementation is a bit wrong. AdView is a separate view and its not a LinearLayout. But it should be wrapped in such layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<com.google.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxx"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Also you gonna need an additional file - res\values\attrs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="com.google.ads.AdView">
      <attr name="adSize">
          <enum name="BANNER" value="1"/>
          <enum name="IAB_MRECT" value="2"/>
          <enum name="IAB_BANNER" value="3"/>
          <enum name="IAB_LEADERBOARD" value="4"/>
      </attr>
      <attr name="adUnitId" format="string"/>
      <attr name="backgroundColor" format="color" />
      <attr name="primaryTextColor" format="color" />
      <attr name="secondaryTextColor" format="color" />
      <attr name="keywords" format="string" />
      <attr name="refreshInterval" format="integer" />
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

As for me - i can't get it work this way but only using the code.

Comment: ok i think i will take your advice and try to implement it in the .java file instead...thanks.